# Page is not redirecting to login page after session expire using AJAX

Tags: ajax, session, redirect, model-view-controller

In my MVC project most of the calls to server are done using Ajax. It works smoothly until the session expires. I have added custom attribute to redirect the page to login page once the session gets expired. But when the call is from AJAX then it is not redirecting to login page.

I have gone through many threads regarding this which has basically suggested to use `OnActionExecuted` method of `ActionFilterAttribute` class, but while doing so i am only getting the type `HttpActionExecutedContext` instead of type `ActionExecutingContext`.

Here's my code:

```
public class SessionExpired : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
            {
                //My Code to handle the session event
                base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax functions are used to get data or to post data primarily. If you are trying to redirect to any page using ajax request mechanism then you are going in wrong direction.

Comment: I'm using to ajax to retrieve data only, but when the session is expired then ajax is unable to get data as it can't call the targeted method in controller.

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/712188/MVC-Web-site-Proper-way-to-return-to-Login-screen

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Action Filter that handles session expiration and if session is null, redirect to Login Action.

```
namespace Mayur.Web.Attributes
{
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your time, the problem is that I'm unable to get this type `ActionExecutingContext ` instead i'm having type `HttpActionExecutedContext ` in  `OnActionExecuting` method. Any idea why this is not showing in IntelliSense ?

Comment: Are you able to access the following namespace

    System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext?

Comment: Thanks, now i have implemented the `OnActionExecuting` but still the page is not redirecting to login page. After I debug I found that the `OnActionExecuting` method is getting called multiple times. Any further suggestion would be highly appreciated.